# Pass variable through the page in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, variables, twig, octobercms

Can I pass variable through the page like this?

```
{% set page.price = 2 %}
```

and later get it

```
<div class="price">{{ price }}</div>
```

Or if there any other way to do this?
Im going through the For cycle and need to set price from one of items

Comment: Have you tried just `{% page.price = 2 %}`?

Comment: yes. getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

You can just code:

```
{% set price = 2 %}
```

Then use it:

```
<div class="price">{{ price }}</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to set it via the rst?